# Equivalent of $state.go in Cordova?

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I'm developping a cordova mobile app. How can I redirect the user after Oauth login? What is (in cordova) the equivalent  of the $state.go used in Ionic?
This is my app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router','ngRoute', 'LoginController', 'LogoutController']).config(function ($stateProvider) {
$stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        url: '/app',
        templateUrl: 'index.html',
        controller: 'fbLoginController'
    })

    .state('app.logout', {
        url: '/logout',
        templateUrl: 'views/connect.html',
        controller: 'fbLogoutController'
    });
```

});

Thanks!

Comment: are you using angularJS with Cordova? Then you need to use the UI-Router in Angular: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider

Comment: Yes I'm using angularjs with cordova. I have tested the $state.go but it doesn't work even if I used the .state in the app.js

Comment: We need your code; you have to use the UI-Router package for AngularJS; it's a separate package from AngularJS.

Comment: I have edited my question. Check it please

Answer (score 1):

$state.go is in fact a Angularjs object.

If you want to use this kind of feature, you can put Angularjs in your cordova project.